# web site scraping through Jsoup

Tags: web, screen-scraping, jsoup

I have spent few hours on signing in to web site by using jsoup. But it always gives same login page. 
To clarify the issue I tried with facebook site. It also gives same result.
Below I mentioned my code

```
String url ="http://www.facebook.com/";
Document doc;
doc = Jsoup.connect(url)
      .data("email","abc@gmail.com","pass","xyz")
      .userAgent("Mozilla").post();
System.out.println(doc);
```

can anybody point me where I made a mistake and how can i fix this issue?
In data portion "**email**" and "**pass**" are input field id of facebook login page.
Thank you.

Comment: Jsoup is bad. If you're coming from a java background consider jruby. If you're coming from a beautiful soup background, consider learning anything else.

Comment: true,But I guess Jruby is also call the htmlUnit functions. I have already used the htmlunit. It works for some site perfectly. But only one site i cant scrape the data by signin in to the site. Issue is i could not log in to the site by using htmlUnit. I can log into other sites and scrape data by using htmlUnit. Thank you

Comment: @pguardiario: can you please elaborate on why jsoup is bad?

Comment: jsoup is a port of a no longer maintained python library. Learning to use it would be a waste of time since there are better libraries that are being maintained.

Comment: May be i have made some mistakes with jsoup. I tried my best to scrape the login part of the web sites. Then i use perl for my work. It has nice library call WWW::Macanize. It is more easy then others.

Comment: @pguardiano, beside your comment I couldn't find any reference on Jsoup being a port besides your comment. Would you mind linking some references? Actually, I found this question looking for a Python port of Jsoup, because it has better API, better invalid HTML handling and a more powerful selector syntax than beatifulsoup4, the _de facto_ standard for Python. Also, could you please mention some of those "better libraries" that you mentioned? From my +4 years of experience writing scrapers in Python and Java, Jsoup is still one of the best tools for this task.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
String url ="http://www.facebook.com/";
        Document doc;
        doc = Jsoup.connect(url)
        .data("email","abc@gmail.com")
        .data("pass","xyz")
        .userAgent("Mozilla")
        .post();
```

Anyway, Jsoup **is not bad at all**, you only need how to use it properly, but also you need to keep in mind that Facebook is expecting a lot more parameters to make a successfull login via POST emulating a web page navigation.

By example:

charset_test
default_persistent
lgnjs
lgnrnd
locale
lsd 
pass
persistent
timezone

If you need to authenticate and get proper data I suggest that you must give a try to a Facebook SDK for Android:

https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk/

Comment: Thank you, I went through what u said,but still same thing happens. I put all the parameters for user login  form post.